# C# - Response internal objects are being disposed and throwing System.ObjectDisposedException: IFeatureCollection has been disposed

Tags: c#, server-sent-events

I'm working on a project that uses Server Sent Events which keeps an open connection and push data to the Response stream. But from time to time I'm getting this exception "System.ObjectDisposedException: IFeatureCollection has been disposed." from Response inner objects, like BodyWriter.

This is the code:

```
public async void SubscribeAsync([BindRequired] string uid, [BindRequired] int tableSource, [FromQuery, BindRequired] List<int> areaIds, int? type = null)
        {
            var allowedAreas = Response.Headers["allowedAreas"].ToString();
            var filteredAreas = areaIds.Where(x => allowedAreas.Contains(x.ToString())).ToList();

            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            UnsubscribeAsync(uid);
            StartKeepAlive(uid);

            if (IsSubscriptionAllowed(uid))
            {
                PushLastStrikes(tableSource, filteredAreas, type);

                while (IsSubscriptionAlive(uid))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var results = (await _strikeWarningRepository.FetchNewStrikesAsync(tableSource, filteredAreas, type)).ToList();
                        _logger.LogInformation("Feeding strikes to the user.");
                        var buffer = 0;
                        
                        do
                        {
                            var bufferedResults = results.Skip(buffer).Take(100).ToList();
                            await Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"data: {JsonSerializer.Serialize(bufferedResults)}\n\n"));
                            await Response.BodyWriter.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                            buffer = buffer + 100;
                        } while (buffer < results.Count);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        UnsubscribeAsync(uid);
                        _logger.LogCritical(ex, "Subscription failed.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using .Net 5.0.

Comment: You have an `async void` there, which is most likely the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you @StephenCleary this was the cause.